# DataGridView virtual mode with a simple list as a source

Tags: c#, list, datagridview, virtual

Previously I asked a question about my dataGridView's performance due to it havign to display a large amount of rows that get added based on an incoming stream. Multiple solutions were given, one of them enabling virtual mode. MSDN has an article on the subject but it feels more complicated than what I need as it uses a database and an editable field. My DataGridView is only for displaying and the data I display is placed in a List.

After I accepted an answer I received this link: http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/23937/Paging-Data-with-DataGridView-in-VirtualMode . Even though that uses a database example, it's better suited for what I need. My List that will contain the data I want to display is declared as follows:

```
List<ResultRow> captureResults = new List<ResultRow>();
```

A ResultRow object is defined as follows:

```
/* Simplified */
public class ResultRow
{
    private int first = 0;
    private string second = "";
    private UInt64 third = 0;
    private IPAddress fourth = null;
    /* etc */

    public ResultRow()
    {
    }

    public void Set (<the values>) //In actuallity a KeyValuePair
    {
        //field gets set here
    }

    public UInt64 Third
    {
        get { return third; }
        set { third = value; }
    }

    /* etc. */
```

}

Following the article mentioned above, i created a ResultRowCache. The object is made as follows:

```
/* Page size set to 100. */
ResultRowCache _cache   = new ResultRowCache(PAGE_SIZE, captureResults);
```

On my form Load event I do the following (related to this problem. I also added an event handler although that's done using the IDE so not directly showing in this code. Definition below!)):

```
dataGrid.VirtualMode = true;

_cache = new ResultRowCache(PAGE_SIZE, captureResults);

dataGrid.Columns.Add("FirstColumn"  , "First column header");
dataGrid.Columns.Add("Second Column", "Second column header");
/* Etc. Adding all columns. (Every member or ResultRow has it's own column. */

dataGrid.RowCount = (int)_cache.TotalCount;
```

One thing I am wondering is how the RowCount is initialized here. It's probably 0 (due to the constructor call of ResultRowCache (see below)) but it never seems to get changed again. Does this assignment count as a reference? How does itupdate itself?

Anyway, onward with what I have, the ResultRowCache is defined as follows:

```
public class ResultRowCache
{
    public int  PageSize    = 100;
    public long TotalCount;
    public List<ResultRow> CachedData = null;
    private List<ResultRow> FullData;

    int _lastRowIndex = -1;

    public ResultRowCache (int pageSize, List<ResultRow> total)
    {
        PageSize = pageSize;
        FullData = total;

        LoadPage( 0 );
    }

    public void LoadPage (int rowIndex)
    {
         int lastRowIndex = rowIndex - ( rowIndex % PageSize );

         /* Page already loaded */
         if( lastRowIndex == _lastRowIndex ) return;

         /* New page */
         _lastRowIndex = lastRowIndex;

         /* Create a new cashes data object */
         if( CachedData == null ) CachedData = new List<ResultRow>();

         /* If cached data already existed, clear */
         CachedData.Clear();

         /* The index is valid (there is data */
         if (lastRowIndex < FullData.Count)
         {
             /* Not a full page */
             if (lastRowIndex + PageSize > FullData.Count)
             {
                 CachedData = FullData.GetRange(lastRowIndex, ((lastRowIndex + PageSize) - 1) - FullData.Count);

             }
            /* Full page */
            else
            {
                CachedData = FullData.GetRange(lastRowIndex, PageSize);
            }
        }

        TotalCount = CachedData.Count;
    }
    }
}
```

Lastly, my CellValueNeeded event for the datagrid is defined as follows:

```
void DataGridCellValueNeededEvent(object sender, DataGridViewCellValueEventArgs e)
{
    _cache.LoadPage(e.RowIndex);

    int rowIndex = e.RowIndex % _cache.PageSize;

    switch (dataGrid.Columns[e.ColumnIndex].Name)
    {
        /* Not actual names, example */
    case "FirstColumn":   e.Value = _cache.CachedData[rowIndex].First;  break;
        case "SecondColumn":  e.Value = _cache.CachedData[rowIndex].Second; break;
        /* Rest of the possibly columns/ResultRow values */
    }
}
```

The problem: My datagrid remains empty even though the "captureResults" list gets filled. Here's what I tried so far:

- Update the RowCount member of the datagrid after the switch in the event.
- Declare the list with the total amount of results within the cache to ensure it's always up to date. (I was afraid "outside modifications" wouldn't go through to the List i passed in the cached constructor even though it was a reference. (Fairly new with C#))
- Set the RowCount of the datagrid to 100 (hard value) in the form's load event.
- Added an "Update()" call to the datagrid after adding something to the captureResults list. (this happens from a special thread which Invoke's a function that adds something to the list)

None of the above changed anything. The grid remains empty. I think I am missing something quite obvious here. Any suggestions?

-edit- Added something I tried to make it work.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I feel that the use of Cache is complicating the process somewhat (although I do feel responsible after sending you the link to the msdn one which implements in this fashion).

What I would recommend as a starting point is:

1. Throw away the cache (this may be useful later if you run into memory problems, but for now lets just get your datagrid populating)
2. Store your `List<ResultsRow>` in an instance variable.
3. Ensure that `dataGrid.VirtualMode = true;` (or equivilant)
4. Implement CellValueNeeded as follows:

   ```
       private void gridContacts_CellValueNeeded(object sender,  DataGridViewCellValueEventArgs e)
       {
          ResultRow dataObject = resultRows[e.RowIndex];

          switch(e.ColumnIndex)
          {
              case 0:
                  e.Value = dataObject.First;
                  break;
              case 1 :
                  e.Value = dataObject.Second;
                  break;
              //etc..
          }
       }
   ```

Note : you will need to expose some extra public properties in DataObject so that they can be set as Values in the method.

See how you get on with that. If you set some breakpoints within the CellValueNeeded method that should help with debugging any further unexpected behavior. Good luck.

Comment: I managed to get it working (without cache) by updating the RowCount after every addition with the size of my list. Performance appears worse however. (Maybe because I am updating the form every addition, instead of every <x> ms by a background worker) My application also freezes relatively quickly after processing data. Is it a wrong implementation of virtual mode or does the problem lie elsewhere? (for some reason drawing the rows (that can have different background colors) is very difficult for this system. My laptop (which is more powerful) can do it more easily.

Comment: How come you are updating the RowCount after each addition? Can you share this code, as I'm not sure how that works, and doesn't sound quite right. If you assign your List<ResultRow> to a bindingSource, which is then assigned to Grid.DataSource then rowCounts and internal lists should be tracked sufficiently.

Comment: Ah, I think this is the result of my lack of understanding about the concept. I did not set a datasource for my DataGridView when I enabled virtual mode as I assumed this was the performance problem. If I keep that in tact the only difference is that I set the VirtualMode property to true, and defined the CellValueNeeded event. Is this correct? I don't quite understand why this takes out the performance hit you would get otherwise. Is it the default implementation of the event that is so inefficient for large sets? Overriding it with virtual mode off probably will not work, I'll have to read.

Comment: Ran out of characters on my last post, but I wanted to add that I will try my code with the data source enabled and the rowcount updating disabled. I'll let you know the results! (I cannot test this immediately unfortunately)

Comment: It really depends, you shouldn't be getting any sort of performance hit if you implement it properly. However.. if you had an auto-property that in turn populated some child properties of your DataRow from a database, you would get a performance hit. That's just one example of many, It's very hard to help you without seeing the code, would you mind posting a follow up?