# Application hangs when loading data

Tags: c#, winforms

In my C# Desktop application, I want to show all temporary files in a datagridview but when the datagridview is loading, my program hangs and is not responsive until the datagridview is completely loaded.

How can I make it such that my application is still alive while execution is still going on?

Comment: What does your application code look like? Are you multi-threading at all?

Comment: Have a look at this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10512981/datagridview-virtual-mode-with-a-simple-list-as-a-source

Comment: i did not use any threading but i can implement threading . But can you ensure me that the problem will not come if i use threading .

Comment: @AnimeshDatta: we can't ensure that you won't find a different problem.  But, good use of threading is the correct solution to an application that hangs during long-running operation.

Comment: in my application i use this code                                                    {  ThreadStart threadstatr = new ThreadStart(My_FunctionName);
       
            Thread thread = new Thread(threadstatr);
            thread.Start();   }  but programs still hangs  please provide some solution

Answer (score 3):

Have a look at using

[BackgroundWorker Class](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.componentmodel.backgroundworker.aspx)

> The BackgroundWorker class allows you to run an operation on a
>   separate, dedicated thread. Time-consuming operations like downloads
>   and database transactions can cause your user interface (UI) to seem
>   as though it has stopped responding while they are running. When you
>   want a responsive UI and you are faced with long delays associated
>   with such operations, the BackgroundWorker class provides a convenient
>   solution.

Answer (score 1):

Use [BackGroundWorker](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.componentmodel.backgroundworker.aspx) to Load the grid. It is a separate `dedicated thread`. Read these articles before implementing

http://www.dotnetperls.com/backgroundworker

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc221403(v=vs.95).aspx