# Create virtual mode to populate DataGridView from a string array or List<string> in C#

Tags: c#, memory, datagridview

When I populate the `DataGridView` (in a `for` loop) with rows which are stored in a `string[] myData`, the system starts using too much RAM, the GUI freezes and sometimes I get the **OutOfMemoryException** error.

I have read that **virtual mode** populates the DataGridView on demand and uses less RAM.

However, every example I have found uses a database (or some other data source). My values are string values which are read from a file and stored in an array variable:

```
string[] myData = obj.GetFileContent(file);
```

What I have tried so far:

```
dataGridView1.VirtualMode = true;
```

Created the `DataGridViewCellValueEventHandler`:

```
private void dataGridView1_CellValueNeeded(object sender, DataGridViewCellValueEventArgs e) {
          //...
}
```

My `DataGridView` has 6 columns and the files that are read can be around 1GB in size. I have tried to follow 
[this thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10512981/datagridview-virtual-mode-with-a-simple-list-as-a-source), but couldn't figure out how to use my `string[] myData` to populate the DataGridView.

**EDIT:**

The file lines are read and stored in the array as elements. So the first element in the array is the first line in the file, etc. Later I will use some kind of sorting (Regex) to sort parts of the line into the columns.

The array elements are placed in the columns like this:

```
for(int i = 0; i < myData.Count(); i++)
{ 
    dataGridView1.Rows.Add(); 
    dataGridView1.Rows[i].Cells[0].Value = (i + 1); //first column
    dataGridView1.Rows[i].Cells[5].Value = myData[i]; //sixth column
}
```

I want to populate only as much of data as can be displayed in the DataGridView. Only when a user scrolls down (and up), more data should be populated.

Comment: The file lines are read and stored in the array as elements. So the first element in the array is the first line in the file, etc. Later I will use some kind of sorting (Regex) to sort parts of the line into the columns.

Comment: How are you currently allocating the array element to the columns?

Comment: The array elements are placed in the columns like this: `for(int i = 0; i < myData.Count(); i++) { dataGridView1.Rows.Add(); dataGridView1.Rows[i].Cells[0].Value = (i + 1);  //first column dataGridView1.Rows[i].Cells[5].Value = myData[i]; //sixth column }`

Comment: If you parse out your file lines as an array of objects - even if the object only has one string property for now - instead of an array of strings, perhaps you can then use that as the `DataSource` or more closely follow the thread you posted.

Comment: @OhBeWise Do you mean parsing each part of the line into a separate array? So for example: the integers (ID) should be saved in `int[] IDs` and the string (name) should be saved in `string[] names` ? During the reading of contents from the file, a `string content; content = reader.ReadLine()` is used in a `while` loop. The `content` string variable then gets added to a `List<string> retVal`.. `retVal.Add(content);` .. which should then be used to populate the DataGridView.

Comment: Say each line of your file has an ID and a Name and currently you parse them out together in a single string, and each line makes up a single entry in your string array. Instead, create a class object - `MyObject` - with a public int/string property for `ID`, and a public string property for `Name`. Then create an array - `MyObject[]`. Each line in your file could then be parsed out as a `MyObject`.

Comment: And to parse out the various parts of a line, a Regex would be needed in the while loop that is used to read the files?

Answer (score 0):

You did not get the concept of `VirtualMode` : you do not have to fill the rows & cells of your `DataGridView`.

At `DataGridView` initialization, just set the number of rows : `DataGridView.RowCount = myData.Length;`

Then, implement the [`CellValueNeeded`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/fr-fr/library/system.windows.forms.datagridview.cellvalueneeded(v=vs.110).aspx) event handler or your `DataGridView` :

```
private void dataGridView1_CellValueNeeded(object sender, DataGridViewCellValueEventArgs e)
{
    if (e.ColumnIndex == 0)
        e.Value = e.RowIndex + 1;
    else if (e.ColumnIndex == 5)
        e.Value = myData[e.RowIndex];
}
```